# The set $A=\{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:|x|=|y|\}$ is connected

Tags: analysis

Two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$, neither empty, are said to be **mutually separated** if neither contains a boundary point of the other. A set is disconnected if it is the union of separated subsets, and is called **connected** if it is not disconnected.

With the above definition of connected set, how to prove that the set $A=\{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:|x|=|y|\}$ is connected.

Exercise should try using the definition of previous related and for this I guess I should do the proof by contradiction but do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove that $\{y=x\}$ and $\{y=-x\}$ are connected. Since they have a point in common, their union is. Can you try to argue this is the same, in essence, than showing the real line is connected?

First, let's obtain a slightly more useful equivalent to your definition. First, if $A,B$ are open sets and $A\cap B=\varnothing$, then they are separated. Now suppose $A,B$ are separated sets, and $C=A\cup B$. Then $C\setminus \bar A$ and $C\setminus \bar B$ are relatively open in $C$. But $$(A\cup B)\setminus \bar A=B$$ since $B\cap \bar A=\varnothing$. Thus $C=A\cup B$ and $A,B$ are relatively open in $C$. We can then just say that a set $C$ is disconnected if it can be written as the disjoint union of relatively open subsets of $C$.

Now, suppose $f:C\to C'$ is continuous and onto. If $C'$ is disconnected by $A,B$, then $C$ is disconnected by the open sets $f^{-1}(A)$, $f^{-1}(B)$. Thus, by the contrapositive, if $C$ is connected, so must be $C'$. That is, the image of a connected set under a continuous function is connected.

Now consider the function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$ given by $f(x)=(x,x)$. Then your set is $f(\Bbb R)$. I hope you know that $\Bbb R$ is connected. You should see $f$ is continuous: $$\lVert f(x)-f(y)\rVert^2=2(x-y)^2$$

so if $x$ and $y$ are close, so is $(x,x)$ and $(y,y)$. Thus, $f(\Bbb R)$ is connected.

It is also true that the union of connected sets with non-empty interesction is connected. And one can prove it as follows. First, we prove that $C$ is connected if and only if the only continuous functions $f:C\to\{0,1\}$ $-$ where $\{0,1\}$ is given the discrete metric (topology), that is, **all** sets are open $-$ are constant.

If $C=A\cup B$ with $A,B$ open, then we can define $f(a)=1$ when $a\in A$ and $f(b)=0$ when $b\in B$, to get non constant continuous function $f:C\to\{0,1\}$. Conversely, if we had a  non-constant continuous function $f:C\to\{0,1\}$, we could write $C=f^{-1}(\{0\})\cup f^{-1}(\{1\})$ where this two sets are open and disjoint.

With this out of the way, suppose that we have a collection $\mathscr C$ of connected sets, and they have a point in common, call it $c$, that is $\bigcap\mathscr C\neq \varnothing$. Consider a continuous function $f:\bigcup \mathscr C\to \{0,1\}$. We will show that $f(x)=f(c)$ for any $x\in\bigcup\mathscr C$. Indeed, pick $x$ in the union. Then this belongs to some of the sets in the collection, call this set $C_x$. Then $f$ as a function from $C_x$ to $\{0,1\}$ is still continuous, so, since $C_x$ is connected, it must be constant. But $c\in C_x$; so we must have $f(x)=f(c)$. Since this $x$ was arbitrary, the claim follows.

Comment: Tamaroff...how to prove that $A=\{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:y=x\}$ is connected?

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero One usually shows that continuous functions map connected sets to connected sets.

Comment: Peter in the course have not seen my teacher continuity of functions you want the test to be performed only using the definition of connectedness given

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero Are you really studying connectedness without knowing about continuity...?

Comment: yes...is that what you want is to do the exercise only with the definition ... I know of a related image under a continuous function is connected and parameterization can prove that a segment is connected ... but I wonder if the exercise can be performed using only the definition of related, perhaps through a contradiction

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero I guess it would be very tortous. I'd rather develop the machinery to make the proofs easy! Cf. my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know  straight lines are connected set in $\mathbb{R}^2$? do you know union of connected set is connected if they have one point in common?

Now can you see your set with above stated properties?

Comment: Senore how to prove that the straight lines are connected set in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: a straigh line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is homeomorphic to real line which is connecetd

Answer (score -1):

If |x| < |y| then those x's are all in the disk of radius y about the origin.  That is surely connected

Comment: Betty sorry the set is $A=\{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:|x|=|y|\}$

Comment: $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$ is a subset of $[0,1]$ which is connected, but the rationals are surely not connected.

Comment: @Roiner -- don't know how I misread that -- my version of the problem is easier anyway.  B

Comment: -1: This is not written carefully enough for me to easily perceive its meaning, but it certainly does not answer the OP's question, i.e., give a proof of the connectedness of the locus $y = \pm x$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.